# Using bit operations to "turn off" binary digits of a pointer

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit, bitwise-operators

I was able to use bit operations to "turn off" binary digits of a number.

Ex:
x = x & ~(1<<0)
x = x & ~(1<<1)
(and repeat until desired number of digits starting from the right are changed to 0)

I would like to apply this technique to a pointer's address.

Unfortunately, the & operator cannot be used with pointers.  Using the same lines of code as above, where x is a pointer, the compiler says "invalid operands to binary & (have int and int)."

I tried to typecast the pointers as ints, but that doesn't work as I assume the ints are too small (and I just realized I'm not allowed to cast).

(note: though this is part of a homework problem, I've already reasoned out why I need to turn off some digits after a good couple hours, so I'm fine in that regard.  I'm simply trying to see if I can get a clever technique to do what I want to do here).

Restrictions: I cannot use loops, conditionals, any special functions, constants greater than 255, division, mod.

(edit: added restrictions to the bottom)

Comment: It's not unfortunate that bitwise operation don't work on pointers.

Comment: @tangrs That I need to turn off digits somehow just so happens to be a solution I would like to implement, because I've reasoned out it is sufficient to perform the task of a function.  Because I'm limited in what I can use, I've resorted to using bit manipulation.

Comment: I don't know how you're going to manipulate a pointer with bitwise operations without casting (all the answers assume you can cast). This sounds like an X-Y problem - what are you *really* trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't a good way to achieve your goal, whatever that is. its probably an X-Y problem (Google it). otherwise, try pointer arithmetic. its not bitwise, but its supported and wont invoke UB if used right

Comment: @tangrs How unfortunate haha.  I need a function to show two pointers are in the same 64-byte block of memory.  This holds true so long as every digit but the least significant 6 digits of their binary representations are equal.  By making sure the last 6 digits are all the same (ex: 0), I can return true if both pointers are equal.  Well, at least I hope so.

Comment: And well, considering it's illegal to return an expression, pointer x & y, I guess that destroys my whole plan.

Comment: `if ((char *)high_pointer - (char *)low_pointer < 64)` perhaps?

Comment: @tangrs, Undefined behaviour if the two pointers are not part of the same object (e.g., an array).

Comment: @tangrs I actually need clarification on the question, but I don't believe that works because they might fall on different "64-byte blocks"; but I don't know the specific definition of a 64-byte block.  Also, I cannot use greater/less than conditionals.

Comment: @chris You're probably right. That begs the question though, does a portable way that doesn't invoke implementation-defined/undefined behaviour even exist?

Answer (score 4):

Use `uintptr_t` from [`<stdint.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer). You should always use unsigned types for bit twiddling, and `(u)intptr_t` is specifically chosen to be able to hold a pointer's value.

Note however that adjusting a pointer manually and dereferencing it is undefined behaviour, so watch your step. You shall be able to recover the exact original value of the pointer (or another valid pointer) before doing so.

**Edit :** from your comment I understand that you don't plan on dereferencing the twiddled pointer at all, so no undefined behaviour for you. Here is how you can check if your pointers share the same 64-byte block :

```
uintptr_t p1 = (uintptr_t)yourPointer1;
uintptr_t p2 = (uintptr_t)yourPointer2;
uintptr_t mask = ~(uintptr_t)63u; // Shave off 5 low-order bits

return (p1 & mask) == (p2 & mask);
```

Comment: Will work for many architectures but this method isn't portable AFAIK.

Comment: @tangrs Are you referring to the code itself, the definition of a "64-byte block", or somethink else I overlooked ?

Comment: I'm referring to treating the pointer as an integer. I believe the bit/byte pattern for a pointer is implementation defined. Edit: But then again, the concept of having a "64-byte block" may vary across different architectures. I know I'm arguing semantics here but if the OP just wants this to run on a normal Intel/ARM computer for a homework assignment, this code is perfect.

Comment: @tangrs that's perfectly true (and for obvious reasons). Let's say that this code supports platforms where pointers are integer with sensible binary representation and at least 5 bits (i.e, no 3-bit Gray-encoded pointers please). Also note that by caring about pointer locations, we're already in the implementation-defined stuff, so...

Comment: ...and follows a linear memory model :)

Comment: @tangrs Warning : this code doesn't work with qbits. And does.

Answer (score 2):

C language standard library includes the (optional though) type `intptr_t`, for which there is guarantee that "any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer".

Of course if you perform bitwise operation on the integer than the result is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

> How unfortunate haha. I need a function to show two pointers are in
>   the same 64-byte block of memory. This holds true so long as every
>   digit but the least significant 6 digits of their binary
>   representations are equal. By making sure the last 6 digits are all
>   the same (ex: 0), I can return true if both pointers are equal. Well,
>   at least I hope so.

You should be able to check if they're in the same 64 block of memory by something like this:

```
if ((char *)high_pointer - (char *)low_pointer < 64) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Edit2: This is likely to be undefined behaviour as pointed out by chris.

Original post:

You're probably looking for [`intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/). The standard says you can cast to and from these types to pointers and have the value equal to the original.

However, despite it being a standard type, it is optional so some library implementations may choose not to implement it. Some architectures might not even represent pointers as integers so such a type wouldn't make sense.

It is still better than casting to and from an `int` or a `long` since it is guaranteed to work on implementations that supply it. Otherwise, at least you'll know at compile time that your program will break on a certain implementation/architecture.

(Oh, and as other answers have stated, manually changing the pointer when casted to an integer type and dereferencing it is undefined behaviour)